# How to keep table-cell contents the same size with padding?

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS table. I have left and right padding added to each cell. But the first and last cell, I have their first and last (respectively) padding removed. This resizes the contents of the rest of the cell contents (probably because of `border-box`).

How do I prevent this from happening so that all cells have equal sized elements, but I can still remove the "outside" padding of the first and last cells?

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.cell {
  width: 20%;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 30px;
  outline: 1px dotted blue;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.cell:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}
  
.cell:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class='table'>

  <div class='cell'>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200">
  </div>
  
  <div class='cell'>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200">
  </div>
  
  <div class='cell'>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200">
  </div>
  
  <div class='cell'>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200">
  </div>
  
  <div class='cell'>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200">
  </div>
  
</div>

<h1>How do I eliminate the padding on the left and right side but keep all table-cell contents the same size</h1>
```

Comment: can you please explain this more clear , you want to remove the margin or you don't want

Comment: may i know why you need to remove the padding ?

Comment: Your problem is your image width... why don't you constrain it? instead of `100%` do a `pixel` or `em` based width. If seems that you know the dimensions of the images anyway from the urls that you use as `src`. If image `max-width` can be constrained to specific size instead of percentage, I could provide a snippet for you.

Comment: @DavidEspino that won't work if you want the images to be responsive in fluid containers.

Comment: @Naila No. I just do.

Comment: @JakeWilson did you check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your codes , select inside image of the first and last child then use css `calc()` method

```
.cell:first-child img {
   width:calc(100% - 30px);
   float:right;
}
.cell:last-child img {
   width:calc(100% - 30px);
   float:left;
}
```

Check with **snippet**

```css
.table {
   width: 100%;
   display: table;
   max-width: 1000px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
.cell {
   width: 20%;
   display: table-cell;
   padding: 30px;
   outline: 1px dotted blue;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
.cell:first-child {
   padding-left: 0;
}
.cell:last-child {
   padding-right: 0;
}
.cell:first-child img {
   width:calc(100% - 30px);
   float:right;
}
.cell:last-child img {
   width:calc(100% - 30px);
   float:left;
}
img {
   max-width: 100%;
}
h1 {
   margin-top: 2em;
   text-align: center;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class='table'>
  <div class='cell'> <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200"> </div>
  <div class='cell'> <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200"> </div>
  <div class='cell'> <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200"> </div>
  <div class='cell'> <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200"> </div>
  <div class='cell'> <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200"> </div>
</div>
<h1>How do I eliminate the padding on the left and right side but keep all table-cell contents the same size</h1>
```